# Rails application sprocket environment can't find asset on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, heroku, assets, sprockets

For a rails application that I've deployed to heroku, I need to compile different stylesheets for different users and then upload them to Amazon S3. I create a sass file that defines several variables (mostly colors) and then compile this file and temporarily save it to the tmp directory. From there, I immediately save the compiled css file to S3. Below is the code I am using to do this:

```
class StyleCompiler

def initialize stylesheet
    # Load the stylesheet into an instance variable
    @stylesheet = stylesheet

    # Get the type of owner of the stylesheet
    @type = @stylesheet.styleable_type

    # Get the id of the owner
    @id = @stylesheet.styleable_id

    # Create necessary directories if they dont exist
    if !Dir.exists? Rails.root.join("tmp")
        Dir.mkdir Rails.root.join("tmp", "stylesheets")
    end

    if !Dir.exists? Rails.root.join("tmp", "stylesheets")
        Dir.mkdir Rails.root.join("tmp", "stylesheets")
    end

    if !Dir.exists? Rails.root.join("tmp", "stylesheets", "#{@type}_#{@id}")
        Dir.mkdir Rails.root.join("tmp", "stylesheets", "#{@type}_#{@id}")
    end
end


def compile_erb
    # Path to the erb stylesheet
    @erb_path = File.read(File.join(Rails.root, 'lib', 'assets', 'styles.scss.erb'))

    # Compile erb file
    @definitions = ERB.new(@erb_path).result(binding)
end


def save_to_assets
    File.open(Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "stylesheets", "definitions.css.scss"), 'w') {|f| f.write @definitions}
end


def compile_sass
    # Append the necessary sass import to the definitons file
    @manifest = @definitions += "\n\n@import 'include';"

    # Write Stylesheet to temp location as a sass file
    @manifest_name = "manifest_#{Time.now.to_i.to_s}.scss"
    @temp_path = Rails.root.join("tmp", "stylesheets", "#{@type}_#{@id}", @manifest_name)
    File.open(@temp_path, 'w') {|f| f.write @manifest}

    # Copy the default rails sprocket environment
    sprockets = Rails.application.assets.dup

    puts sprockets.paths

    # Find the desired manifest file that was just created
    asset = Rails.application.assets.find_asset "#{@type}_#{@id}/#{@manifest_name}"

    # Write the compiled css file to a temporary location
    @compiled_name = "compiled_#{Time.now.to_i.to_s}.css"
    asset.write_to Rails.root.join("tmp", "stylesheets", "#{@type}_#{@id}", @compiled_name)
end


def upload
    # Configure S3 variable
    s3 = AWS::S3.new(
        :access_key_id => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],
        :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY']
    )

    # Get Bucket
    bucket = s3.buckets['watsco-cdn']

    # Delete the old css file
    if @stylesheet.url != nil
        old_obj = bucket.objects[@stylesheet.url.split(".net/").last]
        old_obj.delete
    end

    # Upload
    @stylesheet_name = "stylesheet_" + Time.now.to_i.to_s
    obj = bucket.objects["#{@type}_#{@id}/#{@stylesheet_name}.css"]
    obj.write(:file => Rails.root.join("tmp", "stylesheets", "#{@type}_#{@id}", @compiled_name), :acl => :public_read)

    # Save new url to stylesheets
    @stylesheet.url = "http://ddyjn572xhp9e.cloudfront.net/#{@type}_#{@id}/#{@stylesheet_name}.css"
    @stylesheet.save!

    # Delete Temp Files
    File.delete Rails.root.join("tmp", "stylesheets", "#{@type}_#{@id}", @compiled_name)
    File.delete Rails.root.join("tmp", "stylesheets", "#{@type}_#{@id}", @manifest_name)
end
```

end

Everything works fine locally, however on heroku I keep getting this error:

NoMethodError (undefined method `write_to' for nil:NilClass):
2014-07-27T20:39:44.994773+00:00 app[web.1]:   lib/StyleCompiler.rb:64:in`compile_sass'
2014-07-27T20:39:44.994774+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/dealer.rb:55:in `compile_stylesheet'
2014-07-27T20:39:44.994775+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/dealers_controller.rb:44:in`update_color'

It actually works as soon as I deploy the application and when I run heroku restart. Its strange because I have verified that the asset file I'm looking for exists and is in the directory, however sprockets doesn't seem to see it as I get nil when running asset_find. Any explanation would be really appreciated, because I have no idea why this is happening.